# Should I download all the models/classifiers manually for Stanford NLP "hello world"?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm learning how to use the Stanford NLP library (i.e. learning how to write a "hello world" application) and I'm using for this purposes following [code snippet](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)
But, as usua,l I get a lot of `FileNotFoundException` exceptions, which means, that I haven't downloaded some libraries.

Whether I **should** download manually all these models and include them in my project as foreign resources OR it would be better to extract somehow all these models from the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have all the jars provided in the folder:

stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20/

in your classpath you should have all the resources you need to start with the toolkit.

Could you provide more details about the error you're getting?

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
 at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:448)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:761)
 ... 17 more`

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/dcoref/gender.map.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL`

Comment: So both of those files should be in stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar ; do you have that file in your classpath ?

Comment: I can see in my Intellij IDEA: .m2/repository/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.4.1/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar

Comment: You should change the version for stanford-corenlp to 3.5.2 and then rebuild the project and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem